# How to increment a numeric string by +1 with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following variable:

```
pageID = 7
```

I'd like to increment this number on a link:

```
$('#arrowRight').attr('href', 'page.html?='+pageID);
```

So this outputs 7, I'd like to append the link to say 8. But if I add +1:

> $('#arrowRight').attr('href', 'page.html?='+pageID+1);

I get the following output: 1.html?=71 instead of 8.

How can I increment this number to be pageID+1?

Comment: Almost a perfect example of that "how to add two numbers with jQuery" is no longer a joke!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
parseInt(pageID, 10) + 1
```

Accordint to your code:

```
$('#arrowRight').attr('href', 'page.html?='+ (parseInt(pageID, 10) + 1));
```

Comment: Yes but in context: `'page.html?' + (parseInt(pageID, 10) + 1)` - the subexpression has to be parenthesized.

Comment: parseInt is not required if pageID is already an integer, which it is in OP's question. You don't have to call `parseInt` on an number just to increment it

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this solution does not work with strings that are larger than the size of an integer, So parseInt('800000000000000000', 10) + 1 = 800000000000000000, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

`+` happens to be valid operator for both strings and numbers that gives different results when both arguments are numeric and when at least one is not. One of possible workarounds is to use operator that only have numeric context but gives same mathematical result, like `-`. `some_var - -1` will always be same as adding 1 to `some_var`'s numeric value, no matter if it is string or not.

```
$('#arrowRight').attr('href', 'page.html?='+ (pageID - -1));
```

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be a integer, not a string. Try this:

```
pageID = parseInt(pageID)+1;
```

Then you can do

```
$('#arrowRight').attr('href', 'page.html?='+pageID);
```

Comment: Make sure you pass the second parameter to `parseInt` (10) so that values like "08" and "09" work properly.

Comment: Very true, usually don't work with values that begin with '0' so out of habit I left it out. Nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

All these solutions assume that your number you want to add 1 to is within the machine precision for an integer. So if you have a large enough number within that string when you add 1 to it won't change the number.

For Example:

```
parseInt('800000000000000000', 10) + 1 = 800000000000000000
```

So I wrote a quick solution to the problem

```
function addOne(s) {
    let newNumber = '';
    let continueAdding = true;
    for (let i = s.length - 1; i>= 0; i--) {
        if (continueAdding) {
            let num = parseInt(s[i], 10) + 1;
            if (num < 10) {
                newNumber += num;
                continueAdding = false;
            } else {
                newNumber += '0';
            }
        } else {  
            newNumber +=s[i];
        }
    }
    return newNumber.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Now, using the same example above

```
addOne('800000000000000000') + 1 = '800000000000000001'
```

Note that it must stay as a string or you will lose that 1 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, `$('#arrowRight').attr('href', 'page.html?='+(pageID+1));`

The parentheses makes the calculation done first before string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your order of operations by wrapping your addition in parentheses; if pageID is already a number, parseInt() isn't necessary:

```
$('#arrowRight').attr('href', 'page.html?='+(pageID+1));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/KX9Q8/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let pageId = '7'
pageId++
console.log(pageId)
```

Nowadays, you just need to pageID++.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your pageID is numeric, this should be sufficient:

```
$('#arrowRight').attr('href', 'page.html?='+(pageID+1));
```

The problem you were seeing is that JavaScript normally executes in left-to-right order, so the string on the left causes the `+` to be seen as a concatenator, so it adds the 7 to the string, and then adds 1 to the string including 7.